# Django Q set too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django, filter

I am new to django and trying to filter multiple fields that contain text.

```
columns = ['ticketId', 'checkSum']
q_objects = [Q(fieldname +'__contains', myString) for fieldname in columns]
objects = objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_objects))
```

I get 
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: too many values to unpack on the "filter" last line. Any ideas

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? I think your problem is likely to be in the line above, where the `Q` object instantiation doesn't look right. It should be `Q(**{fieldname +'__contains': myString})` - passing it two separate arguments as you are doing will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Q(**{fieldname + '__contains': myString})
```

This is equivalent to providing a keyword argument, as you normally would when instantiating a Q object. For example:

```
Q(fieldname__contains=myString, another_fieldname__contains=myOtherstring)
```

The Q object essentially needs pairs of values to work. Looking at the code it seems you can also use tuples of length two, like this (I haven't tested, though):

```
Q(("fieldname__contains", myString), ("another_fieldname__contains", myOtherString))
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the model you are querying? It looks like you left that out.

The last line,

```
objects = objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_objects))
```

Should be something like

```
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(...)
```